# Interaction plot

Tags: r, plot, model

I am interested in representing an interaction effect among continuous variables in which the effect of one variable (X1) on Y depends on another variable (X2).

I have a code similar to this:

> ```
> X1 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
> X2 <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
> error <- rnorm(1000,0,0.5)
> intercept <- 5
> coef_1 <- 0.5
> coef_2 <- 1
> coef_3 <- -1.5  
> Y <- intercept + coef_1*X1 + coef_2*X2 + coef_3*X1*X2 + error
> data <- data.frame(Y=Y,X1=X1,X2=X2)
> fit <- lm(Y ~ X1*X2,data=data)
> summary(fit)
> ```

There are multiple ways to represent the interaction effect like 3D-plots and the `interaction_plot()`. However, I would like to have an output similar to this:

[image]

I had in mind to do it with the `segments()` function though any other advice would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to make a SHAP plot? https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-any-models-with-the-shap-values-use-the-kernelexplainer-79de9464897a

Comment: Thanks for the link @YacineHajji. I will take a look at it though I am unsure if there is a way to represent interaction effects

Comment: Maybe a scatter plot with each dot colored with a palette of color should be sufficient, for example https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/2635